# mysql query monitor

Tags: mysql, performance, monitoring

I have mysql server.

I need a free monitor (something similar to the mysql enterprise monitor http://www.mysql.com/common/images/enterprise/EnterpriseDashboard.png).
I need the graphs to be in browser.

In the moment I am using munin but i seek for something more powerful.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cacti + Plugins should be able to give you what you need.